# Which part of the verb should I conjugate in a causative sentence when expressing "allowance"?

Tags: conjugations, causation, giving-and-receiving

I am unsure which part of the verb to conjugate when making a causative sentence expressing "allowance". For example, if I were to write 'My mother didn't let (allow) me get a drivers license, would I write:

> a. 母は僕に免許を取得させなくてくれた

OR

> b. 母は僕に免許を取得させてくれなかった

Which of these conjugation options is more natural/makes sense?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant 免許 instead of 免除 too?

Comment: 取得 is a bit stiff here. 取る sounds more natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second sentence is the correct one in your situation. You need to negate the action of "giving (the favor of letting me get a driver's license)" using なかった.

なくてくれた is grammatically incorrect regardless of the situation, but ないでいてくれた can be valid depending on the situation:

- 母はそれを言わないでいてくれた。
  My mother didn't say it, which I am thankful for.
  My mother kindly kept it a secret.
- 母は僕に免許を取らせないでいてくれた。
  My mother kindly prevented me from getting a driver's license.
  <sup>(She might have known I would be a poor driver)</sup>

Here, you're thankful for your mother's "not doing something".